# Unable to delete a document with passed "email" and "_id" anyhow

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I wanted to delete a document with concerned _id and email when I click on "Remove task" in the HTML file.

Following is the code which removes that task:
I've passed value of email and _id(only hexadcemial string value) to the code:

```
collection.findOneAndDelete({email:email,_id:taskid},function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log("Removed!");
                    console.log(result);
                    callback(result);
                }
                db.close();
            });
```

But, the function is not recognizing _id that I've passed. The value of "taskid" variable is `566836bd8db43d3d56e23a4a` i.e. only strings value from _id:

```
ObjectId("566836bd8db43d3d56e23a4a")
var taskid=566836bd8db43d3d56e23a4a;
```

I've tried every possible declaration of taskid to convert it so that the function could recognize the value of _id and match it:

```
var taskid= "ObjectId("+'"'+req.param('taskid')+'"'+")";
```

But till now, I am not able to match the _id with the taskid. Any fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are going to compare with ObjectId then

```
var ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId

collection.findOneAndDelete({email:email,_id:new ObjectId(taskid)},function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log("Removed!");
                console.log(result);
                callback(result);
            }
            db.close();
        });
```

Should work for you.

If you feel the job too hard for each and every query then you can create an new method.

```
    String.prototype.toObjectId = function() {
  var ObjectId = (require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId);
  return new ObjectId(this.toString());
};

// Every String can be casted in ObjectId now
console.log('545f489dea12346454ae793b'.toObjectId());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir but I dont use mongoose. Are there any other options?

Comment: if you are using a raw mongodb module then i recommend to you to see this https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/objectid.html